# authentication of user and admin separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

basically i have Admin and User in my app. Here after signing  by user it is also routing user_dashboard but if i make change in url as admin_dashboard it is getting routed for that also. How can i stop that

similarly if Admin get sign in it is also routing to Admin_dashboard but if i make change in url as user_dashboard it get routed. How can i restrict that

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user! , :only => ["welcome#index"]

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)  
     user_dashboard_index_path
   end

   def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
    welcome_index_path
  end
end
```

Comment: you can use gems like active_admin ... ? or u can create a action in controller and add before_filter option in your controller ... In that action u can put your correspoidng cod e..

Comment: You can also create a scope for user and admin if you are using devise gem. and if you want your admin and user both separately then for user authentication use devise and for admin panel use Active-Admin Gem.

Comment: How do you identify your admin and user? is there any field you have?

Comment: Seems suspiciously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212211/authenticate-user-and-admin-seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way to do this is to [override the devise `before` and `after_sign_in_path_for` helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out)

I think ([from what I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385288/devise-active-admin-redirect)), you can use logic to determine the best way to handle this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) ||
    if resource.is_a?(Admin)
      admin_dashboard_path
    else
      user_path(resource)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any field like "is_admin" in user model then you need to just check whether logged in user is admin or not.

like

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if user.is_admin?
    admin_dashboard_index_path
  else
    user_dashboard_index_path
  end
end
```

Comment: error after changing as per above  NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#new

undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x9063cf0>

Comment: Do you have any field in user model like is_admin?, if not then take one and store is_admin = true by default. or you can do it as per your requirement.